# Warnings are being treated as errors in Codeblocks 16.01

Tags: c++, c, gcc, codeblocks, bgi

I am trying to build a cpp program in codeblocks, that includes graphics.h file in it.

But I am getting a

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' 
>                 [-Wwrite-strings]
>
> ```
>   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
> ```

The warning is treated as errors: I have modified all the linker settings to include graphics.h in codeblocks.

```
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
```

Codeblocks shows:

> === Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===

Comment: It is not a linker error. Note that the function `void initgraph(int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver);` does not use the `const` qualifier for `pathtodriver` (even though this is not an output parameter), but you pass a read-only argument.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Mate, cpp compiler compiles c code. And initgraph() is a c function in graphics.h, so my question and tags are all appropriate.

Comment: "Warnings are being treated as errors". This is **exactly** what you want. Don't touch this setting,

Comment: Did you specify to treat warnings as errors? To fix this warning try `static char emptystring[] = ""; /* ... */ initgraph(&gd, &gm, emptystring);`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "cpp program"̇. There is a language called C, and a language called C++. These are two different languages.

Comment: Adding C++ tag since the issue is about cross compiling old C libs in C++.

Comment: A C++ compiler compiles C++ code. A C compiler compiles C code. A C compiler might compile an excerpt of C++ code, as it could look like it makes sense as C. A C++ compiler might compile an excerpt of C code as it could look like it makes sense as C++.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C++ nowadays `const` qualify all string literals, unlike C and pre-standard C++. TC++ and Borland BGI is from the pre-standard days, so it won't compile cleanly with standard C++.

Best work-around:

```
char empty[] = "";
initgraph(&gd, &gm, empty);
```

Quick & dirty work-around:

```
initgraph(&gd, &gm, (char*)"");
```

You might also want to ask yourself why you are using 30 years old outdated libs written for MS DOS.

Comment: The next question would be from the linker errors, solution is `extern "C"`, then followed by "why does it not work..." :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And then I haven't got the slightest idea how to link the ancient 16 bit Borland BGI library with Codeblocks/Mingw64.